# How to make functions from all namespaces available in the .core namespace in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, namespaces

I have a library that has multiple namespaces. I would like if I could make functions in all namespaces available in the core namespace. This way I could just require `example.core` instead of requiring `example.ns1`, `example.ns2`, etc.

Here is what I have in my core namespace

```
(ns example.core
  (:require [example.options :refer :all]
            [example.playback :refer :all]
            [example.controlls :refer :all]
            [example.stored :refer :all]
            [example.db :refer :all]))
```

here is how i'm trying to require it

```
(ns test-app.core
  (:require [example.core :as e])

(e/foo) ; where foo is defined in one of the namespaces required by example.core
```

When I try to execute that I get `CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: No such var: e/foo`

Is what I'm after possible? or will I have to import the multiple namespaces individually?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `import-vars` from the library [Potemkin](https://github.com/ztellman/potemkin).